# Utilizar un objeto que devuelve una función en otra

Tags: c++, clase

Estoy intentando crear una función que utilice un objeto devuelto por otro método de la misma clase y no consigo que la nueva función lo utilice. Este es el caso:

```
Paciente Paciente::getPaciente(){
    string nombre, apellidos;
    Paciente J("");
    cout << "Introduce el nombre: ";
    cin >> nombre;
    J.setNombre(nombre);
    cout << "Introduce los apellidos: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, apellidos);
    J.setApellidos(apellidos);

    list <Paciente>::iterator it;

    for (it=listapacientes_.begin(); it!=listapacientes_.end(); it++){

        if ((*it).getNombre()==J.getNombre() and (*it).getApellidos()==J.getApellidos()){

        cout << "Paciente Encontrado";

        return (*it);
        }

    }
    cout << "Paciente no encontrado";
}


void Paciente::modificarPaciente(){  
    int opcion;

    Paciente J("");

    J = getPaciente();

    cout << "Que quieres modificar: 1. Dni, 2. Nombre, etc..";

    cin >> opcion;

    switch(opcion){

        case 1:{

            string dni;
            cout << "Introduce el nuevo Dni: ";
            cin >> dni;

            J.setDNI(dni);
        }
    }

}
```

Entiendo que esto cuando se ejecuta crea una copia de ese objeto y no me modifica el objeto de la lista. Que podría hacer para que la ultima linea si me modificara el objeto en la lista? Disculpad si he realizado mal la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu idea es poder modificar el objeto original, entonces tienes que devolver una referencia:

```
Paciente & Paciente::getPaciente(){
//       ^ referencia
```

Eso sí, fíjate que hay caminos de la función que no devuelven nada y eso te puede dar problemas. Una posibilidad, dado que las referencias no pueden apuntar a `null`, es lanzar una excepción:

```
Paciente Paciente::getPaciente(){
    // ...

    throw std::runtime_error("Paciente no encontrado");
}
```

Ahora bien, con las mismas también te digo que suena un poco raro que un objeto `X` tenga a su vez una lista de objetos de tipo `X`... ya que está relación es recusiva.

Un `Paciente` no es una lista, de la misma manera que tu eres una persona y no te conviertes en coche cuando vas al trabajo ni te conviertes en una fila cuando estás esperando a pasar por caja en el supermercado.

Es decir, yo te sugiero sacar la lista y la creación de nuevos objetos de tipo `Paciente` de la propia clase `Paciente`. Crea una clase nueva si lo prefieres o usa funciones sueltas... pero mezclarlo todo en un bloque monolítico nunca es una buena idea.

Comment: El problema reside en que quiero que mi ultima linea de código cambie el valor de un atributo del objeto que devuelve la primera función. En la segunda función cuando hago J =getPaciente(), me crea una copia del objeto que devuelve la primera función, y por eso la ultima linea no modifica el atributo del objeto que ha encontrado la primera función. Disculpa si no estoy siendo lo suficientemente claro. Y gracias por el consejo de separar las clases.